# How to stop Foundation's `.columns` class adding padding that ruins mobile optimisation?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm new to Zurb Foundation (5) and am only just now working on a site that uses it. I've come across an issue where these is unwanted empty space to the right when viewing the site on mobile screen sizes (causing a horizontal scroll). On investigation I see this is caused by Foundations `.colunmn` class - specifically the padding:

```
.column, .columns {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: .625rem;
    padding-right: .625rem;
}
```

This seems like an odd thing for Zurb to do, so I'm assuming I've done somthing wrong on my end. My HTML looks like:

```
<div class="title-panel">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
     <!--CONTENT-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="main-panel">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 medium-push-8 columns">
     <!--CONTENT-->
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-8 medium-pull-4 columns">
     <!--CONTENT-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there some way to get rid of this width 100% plus padding issue?

Image of problem. The width of the blue box is 100% but the padding set above adds the green area on the right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this was due to the parent element of the above divs having a .row class. You cannot have 2 .rows one after the other, even if they are separated by other elements and classes. They must be separated by a .column class.